# bash script passing service reply to variable

Tags: bash, ssh, terminal

I am writing a bash script to automate login to ssh. A person gets connected by executing an ssh command and then passing a password. I have automated this by using `sshpass`. Once you are logged in, the server replies with a message "you are logged in". This message is displayed in the terminal, I dont want to display in terminal and instead store in a  bash variable. 
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean like this?

```
VARIABLE=$(ssh otherhost command)
```

This simply executes `command` on *otherhost*, and terminates the SSH session when that finishes.

Answer (score 1):

Check the contents of `/etc/motd` and the `Banner` field in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` [[ref]](http://recursive-design.com/blog/2007/03/27/change-the-ssh-login-message/).  I'm assuming one of these is where the "you are logged in" message is coming from.  Just blank the message and restart sshd.  This will suppress the message.